Excel Vertical to Horizontal Groups VBA
I'm hoping someone can help me with a VBA script to convert a Vertical Table to a Horizontal Table but while preserving grouping. If there are better solutions outside of VBA then I'm open to trying something. I'm using Excel for Mac.
This is what I'm starting with.

All Groups contain a varying number of Rows
All Groups contain the same number of Columns (A - AH / 34 columns)
There are MANY groups (at the moment 432 groups with about 7500 total rows
I could also do this in sub groups - that is, Column C in my dataset could be used to select groups and then only convert these groups.

This VBA script I have currently have will select the current groups based on the Column C Library data name and the active cell:
Sub SelectCurrentLibrary()
Dim searchValue As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim cell As Range
Dim rngToSelect As Range

Set ws = ActiveSheet
searchValue = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Value

' Find the last row in column A
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

' Loop through column A to find matching rows
For Each cell In ws.Range("C3:C" & lastRow)
    If cell.Value = searchValue Then
        If rngToSelect Is Nothing Then
            Set rngToSelect = ws.Range("A" & cell.Row & ":AH" & cell.Row)
        Else
            Set rngToSelect = Union(rngToSelect, ws.Range("A" & cell.Row & ":AH" & cell.Row))
        End If
    End If
Next cell

' Select the final range
If Not rngToSelect Is Nothing Then
    rngToSelect.Select
Else
    MsgBox "No matching rows found."
End If
End Sub




A
B
C
D




GROUP 1
DATA
LIBRARY 1
DATA


GROUP 1
DATA
LIBRARY 1
DATA


GROUP 1
DATA
LIBRARY 1
DATA


GROUP 2
DATA
LIBRARY 1
DATA


GROUP 2
DATA
LIBRARY 1
DATA


GROUP 2
DATA
LIBRARY 1
DATA


GROUP 2
DATA
LIBRARY 1
DATA


GROUP 2
DATA
LIBRARY 1
DATA


GROUP 3
DATA
LIBRARY 2
DATA


GROUP 3
DATA
LIBRARY 2
DATA


GROUP 3
DATA
LIBRARY 2
DATA


GROUP 3
DATA
LIBRARY 2
DATA




I want to convert this vertical arrangement to a horizontal arrangement (shown below) and paste the data into a new Sheet.
I want to add an empty column between each horizontal grouping
I don't need to copy / convert the header to the horizontal version if that makes things easier




A
B
C
D
EMPTY COLUMN
F
G
H
I
EMPTY COLUMN
K
L
M
N
EMPTY .... etc




GROUP 1
DATA
DATA
DATA

GROUP 2
DATA
DATA
DATA

GROUP 3
DATA
DATA
DATA



GROUP 1
DATA
DATA
DATA

GROUP 2
DATA
DATA
DATA

GROUP 3
DATA
DATA
DATA



GROUP 1
DATA
DATA
DATA

GROUP 2
DATA
DATA
DATA

GROUP 3
DATA
DATA
DATA








GROUP 2
DATA
DATA
DATA

GROUP 3
DATA
DATA
DATA








GROUP 2
DATA
DATA
DATA









If I use the VBA script I have above to select the Range, Excel would still need to copy the individual groups out of that range based on Column A Group name.

What specific problem are you having when trying to get this working?  Typically questions with no code (even not-working code is better than none) tend to get closed here.

Please edit your question to include the code you have tried. And also explain why you would need to convert it back again? Just write it to a separate area for review and then delete the area after you've done your review.  Also, how many groups? Excel has only 16,384 columns which would limit you to 468 groups.

@TimWilliams good point, I added a bit of code that I have

@RonRosenfeld I didn't know there was a column limit. The total groups right now is 432. With this in mind I edited my question - I could instead select all groups from the same 'Library' (which is Column C) and just convert these groups to Horizontal, edit the data and then convert back.

I think a better approach would be to use a dictionary object, collecting each group separately; then writing them out horizontally. Also, work with VBA arrays instead of ranges for a significant speed increase. Again, if you are just reviewing the data, why do you need to convert the horizontal back to vertical? There's no reason to destroy the original.

@RonRosenfeld I will look into this thanks. Also, I’m not just reviewing the data, but I’ll be comparing groups and might add / insert lines per group.

Using Dictionary object to get the range of each group.
Microsoft documentation:

Dictionary object

Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic As Object, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, sKey, Sht As Worksheet
    Dim arrData, ColCnt As Long
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set rngData = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    ' load table into an array
    arrData = rngData.Value
    ColCnt = rngData.Columns.Count
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        sKey = arrData(i, 1)
        If objDic.exists(sKey) Then
            Set objDic(sKey) = Union(objDic(sKey), Cells(i, 1))
        Else
            Set objDic(sKey) = Cells(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    If objDic.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Dim r As Range, c As Range
    ' add a sheet for output
    Set Sht = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
    Set c = Sht.Range("a1")
    For Each sKey In objDic.keys
        With objDic(sKey)
            ' write output to sheet
            c.Resize(.Rows.Count, ColCnt).Value = .Value
        End With
        Set c = c.Offset(, ColCnt + 1)
        If c.Column + ColCnt > Sht.Columns.Count Then ' out of space warning
            MsgBox "There is no more space for output."
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub


Update: using Array instead of Dict or Collection.
There are three items in a row in aRes().

aRes(x, 0) : group name from Col A
aRes(x, 1) : start row#
aRes(x, 2) : end row#


Sub Demo3()
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, iR As Long, sKey As String
    Dim arrData, ColCnt As Long, RowCnt As Long, aRes()
    Dim Sht As Worksheet: Set Sht = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Const HEADER_CNT = 2 ' Modify as needed
    With Sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        Set rngData = .Offset(HEADER_CNT).Resize(.Rows.Count - HEADER_CNT)
    End With
    ' Sort table w/o header rows
    rngData.Sort Key1:=rngData.Cells(1), Header:=xlNo
    ' load table into an array
    arrData = rngData.Value
    ColCnt = rngData.Columns.Count
    RowCnt = rngData.Rows.Count
    ReDim aRes(1 To RowCnt, 2)
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        sKey = arrData(i, 1)
        If iR = 0 Then
            iR = 1
            aRes(iR, 0) = sKey: aRes(iR, 1) = i: aRes(iR, 2) = i
        ElseIf aRes(iR, 0) <> sKey Then
            iR = iR + 1
            aRes(iR, 0) = sKey
        End If
        If IsEmpty(aRes(iR, 1)) Then
            aRes(iR, 1) = i
        End If
        aRes(iR, 2) = i
    Next i
    Dim r As Range, c As Range
    ' add a sheet for output
    Dim ShtNew As Worksheet
    Set ShtNew = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
    Set c = ShtNew.Range("a1")
    For i = 1 To iR
        With Range(Sht.Cells(aRes(i, 1) + HEADER_CNT, 1), Sht.Cells(aRes(i, 2) + HEADER_CNT, ColCnt))
            ' write output to sheet
            c.Resize(.Rows.Count, ColCnt).Value = .Value
        End With
        Set c = c.Offset(, ColCnt + 1)
        If c.Column + ColCnt > Sht.Columns.Count Then ' out of space warning
            MsgBox "There is no more space for output."
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub



Thank you for this! Just curious if this is possible using a Collection instead of a Dictionary? I'm using Excel for Mac so I will need to use a 3rd party Dictionary Class to utilize a Dictionary. I actually tried using this class with some other code that was posted with a Dictionary and a Collection and the Collection ended up being much faster. If this is not possible, no worries - I'll give this a shot still. Thanks

@nok I've updated the script. You could get it done with array. Of course, collection is also an option.

This is great. It throws an error because of merged cells (headers) so I changed Header:=xlYes. Then it runs but rows 1 and 2 are both Header Rows. I tried changing the Sht.Range to "A3" but that doesn't seem to work. Also, I'm wondering about a variation that only processes the current Library (based on active cell) - the library name is listed in Column C. So it would run like it does now for each Group but ONLY for Groups with the Library name of the active cell. If that makes sense. So I could do everything with the above code or JUST one library at a time. Thank you so much for this!

To clarify the 'variation' - it would run for each Group but only for Groups based on which Library name (column c) that the active cell currently falls within.

The script was created to address the original question and has been tested with the provided sample data. If you have additional questions, please consider
What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?

Regarding a follow-up question - understood. For this question I still can't get the code to run properly with Header rows. I have 2, but even with a single row as in my example code, the code still processes the header IN the original table - it removes the original header data and shifts the table data UP into the header row. Also, for the 2nd part of the question (to convert the code back to vertical) should that be an additional separate question as well? Thanks

There isn't a header in sample data. Sharing a screenshot about the table with header is helpful to understand your data layout. How to determin how many header rows in the table? Is hard code OK? I would suggest each post focus on one question. But I'm sure the 2nd part is doable.

Oh I intended the A | B | C | D to be the header but that was my mistake as it looks like the column names. This table will always have the same number of headers (2). I tried adding .Offset(2) to the end of CurrentRegion among other things but it messes with the rest of the output. I can look into it further.

Pls try Demo3().

Pls let me know if you post a new question about convert the code back to vertical.

Thank you much for the Demo3()! Yes I'll let you know when I post the conversion back follow up. I just posted a question regarding the Variation that only pulls the data that has the same Library Name (Column C) (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79221348/excel-vertical-to-horizontal-groups-vba-based-on-active-cell-specific-column)

FYI I just posted the convert back to vertical question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79224755/excel-horizontal-to-vertical-groups-vba
