Excel Horizontal to Vertical Groups VBA
Please see here for my original question and the VBA code I'm using.
I recently asked for help converting a Vertical Table into a Horizontal Table while preserving Groups. Now I need to convert the Horizontal Table (that has been modified) back to the Vertical Table.
The Horizontal Table is (Table 1 below) and has a single Header

Each Group has 34 Columns
There is an Empty Column in between each Group
Each Group has a varying number of Rows
I DON'T need the Headers converted
Ideally, the VBA code will convert the table and "paste values" into the first available cell (at the bottom of Column A) of the Sheet "Master"


TABLE 1


I need to convert Table 1 back to this:

TABLE 2



I would suggest using Power Query instead.  You can easily record your steps to perform this task.


Loading Horizontal Tables into an array
Get data from each table, and save in the result array
Write ouput to Master sheet

Sub Hor2Ver()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, r As Long, iR As Long, arrRes(), arrData
    Const HEADER_CNT = 1
    Const SRC_SHT = "Sheet8"  ' update sheetname as needed
    Const DEST_SHT = "Master"
    Dim srcSht As Worksheet: Set srcSht = Sheets(SRC_SHT)
    Dim ColCnt As Long
    ' get the columns count of a sub-table / data block
    Dim mergeSht As Worksheet: Set mergeSht = Sheets(DEST_SHT)
    Const START_COL_DEST = 1 ' or "A"
    Const KEY_ROW = 2
    ' Get the columns count from the 2nd row in Table2 (dest. table)
    ColCnt = mergeSht.Cells(KEY_ROW, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
    Dim dataRng As Range: Set dataRng = srcSht.UsedRange
    If dataRng.Cells(1).Column = 1 Then ' skip the first col on src table
        Set dataRng = dataRng.Offset(, 1)
    End If
    arrData = dataRng.Value
    ReDim arrRes(1 To UBound(arrData, 2) / ColCnt * UBound(arrData, 1), 1 To ColCnt)
    For i = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2) Step ColCnt + 1 ' loop through each block
        For r = LBound(arrData) + HEADER_CNT To UBound(arrData) ' loop through rows
            If Len(arrData(r, i)) = 0 Then Exit For
            iR = iR + 1
            For j = 1 To ColCnt ' load a row
                arrRes(iR, j) = arrData(r, i + j - 1)
            Next
        Next
    Next
    If iR = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Can't find table(s) on sheet " & srcSht.Name
    Else
        Dim targetCell As Range
        Set targetCell = mergeSht.Cells(mergeSht.Rows.Count, START_COL_DEST).End(xlUp)
        If Len(targetCell.Value) > 0 Then
            Set targetCell = targetCell.Offset(1)
        End If
        targetCell.Resize(iR, ColCnt).Value = arrRes
    End If
End Sub



Thank You again for all your help! I'm getting a 1004 runtime error, which seems to be from the last line mergeSht.Cells(lastRow, 1).Resize(iR, ColCnt).Value = arrRes

Pls add Debug.Print lastRow, iR, ColCnt before it to check the value. And I've updated the code to validate iR before populating Master sheet.

Sorry ... my fault. I had added an empty Left Column (Column A) to the source sheet /table that doesn't have data, just a few Buttons. I thought I could get around that by using srcSht.Range("B1")... but that doesn't work, I have to delete the empty Column A (which is fine if necessary). Also, the columns in between the Data in the Source Table are empty but the HEADERS of those columns are not. I did this so that I could use a Button to 'clear' this sheet after I'm done by using the CurrentRegion, so the Headers have a pipe delimiter. If that's a pain to get around I can always remove it.

To clarify, this code works fine when I remove the empty Column A and clear the cells in the Headers between each Group. Thank You again for all your help!

I've updated the code. By the way, I suggest sharing sample data or a table that mirrors the layout of your actual data. It can save a lot of time.

Thank You. Yes, I probably should just start sharing screenshots like you previously suggested instead of spending time building a temp table - because I there is usually something I miss, sorry about that. Something is awry with the updated code - it's putting all the data in Column B and Column C on the Destination Sheet and doesn't seem to be grabbing all the data. I'm going to update my question with a Screenshot.

I updated the question with screenshots.

Assuming that all cells in column A, adjacent to Table1, are fully blank. I've updated the code.

Thank You yes Col A Source cells are blank. Something is still off. The copied data in "Master" is only bringing in Data that spans Col A - K and instead of putting the additional data for Grp 1 in "Column L" it's puts it in Col A below the data it already brought it to Col A - K. And not all data is present - It seems to skip Group 1 of the source table. Your original code works fine, I can always just find another way to clear the data afterwards and I can also move the Buttons elsewhere. BTW, not sure it matters but in some groups - some cells are blank (but I still need these cells).

I’ve uploaded a screenshot of my testing. I believe the difference arises from how the column count of the sub-table is determined. If you could clarify the rule for this, I’ll adjust the code accordingly.

I just tested with data similar to your screenshot (but using the full 34 columns for each Group). It works as long as every cell of every group contains data, but empty cells within a group throw it off. Once again, I take responsibility for that - I suppose  I added "DATA" to signify possible data, but not all cells will always contain data and sometimes a full column(s) might not have data (not including the empty column between the Groups).

Does Table2 always include header rows? If so, the second row could be used to determine the column count of the sub-table.

Table 2 always includes 2 Headers. The bottom most Header of Table 2 lines up with the Header in Table 1 like in the screenshot (34 Columns only - NOT including the Blank Column A of Table 1 / sub-table).

I’ve updated the script and screenshot.

Thank You. It works, but initially I was getting the "Can't find table(s) on sheet ..." and it seems to be because Col A in Table 1 had a background fill. Even after clearing the cell I needed to delete Col A and re-insert it again - and not make any changes to Col A.

Is Const START_COL_SRC = 2 supposed to be used somewhere in the code?

I checked whether the first column was blank, but it turns out it may not always be. While using a constant could resolve the issue, I prefer to make the code more robust. I've updated the script again.

Thank You! Yes, the first column is empty but has a color fill which I was unaware would cause issues. Anyhow, it works great - this will save me hours. I appreciate your help.

This code is only for the specification of the defined parameters.
Sub ConvHorVer()

Set src = Worksheets("Source")
Set tgt = Worksheets("Master")

freerow = tgt.Cells(tgt.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
lastcol = src.Cells(1, src.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For i = 1 To lastcol + 1 Step 35
   src.Cells(1, i).CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0).Resize(src.Cells(1, i).CurrentRegion.Rows.count - 1).Copy tgt.Cells(freerow, 1)
   freerow = tgt.Cells(tgt.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Next i
End Sub

Sheet "Source" before

Sheet "Master" after


Thank You for this alternative. When I run this is a smaller test data set, this copies the data into the Master but it keeps the horizontal form. If I try this with my full data set, it copies the data into the Master, retains the Horizontal Form and also copies the groups 25 times vertically as well.

This is because it works for 35 (wrongly) columns of data. As you have only 34, change Step 36 to Step 35. Sorry.

Thank You, I just tried again and still the same result. And the data duplication vertically of the same groups is happening in both tests - I just didn't notice it before.

In this case there is some data in your separation column. The separation column must be totally empty.  To create a totally empty column use insert column

Ah OK I made sure the separation column was empty by inserting new columns etc. and the code works, but it also still adds Group 2 and Group 3 to the RIGHT on the Master sheet.

Added the screenshots of the two sheets. In the separator column even the header must be empty (row1).
